# symbolicatecrash fails to find .dSYM

Tags: symbolicatecrash

Hi when I run symbolicatecrash script with .dSYM file and crash file, it fails to symbolicate the crash file. Here is what i get;

```
S Version 5.1 Build 11E53
12 binary images remain after pruning:
Foundation, libsystem_notify.dylib, GraphicsServices, UIKit, shell, WebCore, libc++abi.dylib, libobjc.A.dylib, libdispatch.dylib, libsystem_c.dylib, CoreFoundation, libsystem_kernel.dylib, 
($osVersion, $osBuild) = (5.1, 11E53)
$versionPattern = {5.1 (11E53),5.1,11E53}
Symbol directory paths:  
Finding Symbols:
.fetching symbol file for Foundation--[undef] 
Searching []...-- NO MATCH
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of 9ac539ad20833d948fcfaaaa62325704
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == 9AC539AD-2083-3D94-8FCF-AAAA62325704"
@dsym_paths = (  )
@exec_names = (  )
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

..fetching symbol file for libsystem_notify.dylib--[undef] 
Searching []...-- NO MATCH
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of 47db9e1ba7d13818a747382b2c5d9e1b
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == 47DB9E1B-A7D1-3818-A747-382B2C5D9E1B"
@dsym_paths = (  )
@exec_names = (  )
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib

...fetching symbol file for GraphicsServices--[undef] 
Searching []...-- NO MATCH
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of 9c4c679839b93a8485bcb4f73a54288b
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == 9C4C6798-39B9-3A84-85BC-B4F73A54288B"
@dsym_paths = (  )
@exec_names = (  )
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices

....fetching symbol file for UIKit--[undef] 
Searching []...-- NO MATCH
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of 481f9a9d400d3436a84595c8744a8ecc
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == 481F9A9D-400D-3436-A845-95C8744A8ECC"
@dsym_paths = (  )
@exec_names = (  )
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit

.....fetching symbol file for shell--[undef] 
Searching []...-- NO MATCH
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of a12962a4ed843d9c9ac53a035a497426
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == A12962A4-ED84-3D9C-9AC5-3A035A497426"
@dsym_paths = (  )
@exec_names = (  )
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /Users/ilker/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/2ABA6362-F4C4-4ED2-8B31-E17576D8124E/shell.app/shell
```

.dSYM and .app are in the same directory. Am I missing something?

Command line command: ./symbolicatecrash -v app.crash shell.app.dSYM

Comment: this only happens in iOS Simulator though.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, .dSym is a package, and this is incorrect to use. Instead of, we should use real `dSym` file inside that package: `shell.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF` there is another file without `.dSYM` (in your case is `shell`)